# R: efficiently computing summaries of value-subsets whose contents are determined by the relation between two variables

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, data.table, coding-efficiency

I have two tables, `A` and `B`. For each row of table `A`, I want to get some summary statistics for `B$value` where the value of `B$location` is within `100` of `A$location`. I've accomplished this using the for-loop below, but this is  a slow solution that works well when the tables are small but I would like to scale up to a table `A` which is thousands of rows and a table `B` which is nearly a millions of rows. Any ideas of how to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

The for-loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(A)) {    
   subset(B, abs(A$location[i] - B$location) <= 100) -> temp
   A$n[i] <- nrow(temp)
   A$sum[i] <- sum(temp$value)
   A$avg[i] <- mean(temp$value)
}
```

An example:
    `A
    loc
    150
    250
    400`
`B
    loc    value
    25     7
    77     19
    170    10
    320    15`

Would become:
`A
    loc    n    sum    avg
    150    2    29     14.5
    250    2    25     12.5
    400    1    15     15`

Comment: Check again the 3rd row of table `A`. It should be `250` I guess...

Comment: Fixed, thanks for catching the typo!

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Matt Summersgill's answer, you could do a non-equi join to update `A`:

```
A[, up := loc + 100]
A[, dn := loc - 100]
A[, c("n", "s", "m") := 
  B[copy(.SD), on=.(loc >= dn, loc <= up), .(.N, sum(value), mean(value)), by=.EACHI][, .(N, V2, V3)]
]
```

Or in one chained command:

```
A[, up := loc + 100][, dn := loc - 100][, c("n", "s", "m") := 
  B[copy(.SD), on=.(loc >= dn, loc <= up), 
    .(.N, sum(value), mean(value)), by=.EACHI][, 
    .(N, V2, V3)]
]
```

This should be fairly efficient, I guess.

*How it works*

Inside `j` of `x[i, j]`, `.SD` refers to the subset of data from `x` (in this case it's all of `A`).

`x[i, on=, j, by=.EACHI]` is a join, using each row of `i` (in this case `copy(.SD)` == `A`) to look up matching rows of `x` (in this case `B`) using the conditions in `on=`. For each row of `i`, `j` is calculated (which is what `by=.EACHI` means).

When `j` doesn't have names, they are assigned automatically. `V1`, `V2`, and so on. `.N` by default gets named `N`.

Comment: `copy(.SD)` is just `A` isn't it?

Comment: @Arun Yes. I prefer to write .SD instead of the table name when I can to reduce typo risk if I chang the table name or copy-paste the [...] elsewhere. On the version I was using, the join triggered a “don’t modify .SD error” (filed as bug already, I think), so I added copy. I guess I’ve done this same thing in several SO answers already

Answer (score 2):

My pure R solution (below) is still considerably slow,
in my system it required 32 seconds to finish Matt Summersgill's big example,
but compared to other solutions,
it's still reasonable.

The logic of my solution is that,
since the inputs are sorted,
as you consider new elements of `A_loc`,
the range of values in `B_loc` will either stay the same if the new `A_loc` element is identical to the previous,
or it will shift to the right in `B_loc`,
possibly contracting or expanding.
Note that if you were working with `double` inputs,
you'd have to be a bit more careful with the comparisons.

This C++ version is naturally faster.
If you can `Rcpp::sourceCpp` this code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame foo(IntegerVector A_loc, IntegerVector B_loc, IntegerVector B_val) {
    IntegerVector n(A_loc.length());
    IntegerVector sum(A_loc.length());
    NumericVector avg(A_loc.length());

    int lower = 0;
    int upper = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int current_sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < A_loc.length(); i++) {
        checkUserInterrupt();

        while (lower < B_loc.length()) {
            if (B_loc[lower] >= A_loc[i] - 100) {
                break;
            }

            if (count > 0) {
                count--;
                current_sum -= B_val[lower];
            }

            lower++;
        }

        if (upper < lower) {
            upper = lower;
        }

        while (upper < B_loc.length()) {
            if (B_loc[upper] > A_loc[i] + 100) {
                break;
            }

            count++;
            current_sum += B_val[upper++];
        }

        n[i] = count;
        sum[i] = current_sum;
        avg[i] = static_cast<double>(current_sum) / count;
    }

    DataFrame df = DataFrame::create(
        Named("loc") = A_loc,
        Named("n") = n,
        Named("sum") = sum,
        Named("avg") = avg
    );

    return df;
}
```

then this:

```
A <- data.frame(loc = sample.int(1000, size = 1e4, replace = TRUE))


B <- data.frame(loc = sample.int(1000, size = 1e6, replace = TRUE),
                value = sample.int(100, size = 1e6, replace = TRUE))

test <- function() {
    # remove unique if you want to consider duplicated values
    A_loc <- sort(unique(A$loc), decreasing = FALSE)
    B <- B[order(B$loc),]
    out <- foo(A_loc, B$loc, B$value)
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(test())
```

shows these timings:

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min      lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 test() 44.74469 45.8118 51.35361 47.34657 48.99376 95.00938   100
```

If you can't use Rcpp,
then consider the R version below,
or Frank's solution with data.table,
I think sorting the inputs might also help that case?

---

`for` loops are usually avoided in R,
but I don't think they are always slow,
you just have to be careful not to copy data too much.
Also, since R v3.5.0,
writing something like `for i in 1:10` no longer allocates the whole vector first,
it supports compact representation.

```
A_loc <- sort(unique(A$loc), decreasing = FALSE)
B <- B[order(B$loc),]

out <- data.frame(loc = A_loc,
                  n = 0L,
                  sum = 0L,
                  avg = 0)

lower <- 1L
upper <- 1L
count <- 0L
sum <- 0L
upper_limit <- nrow(B)
for (i in seq_along(A_loc)) {
  current_loc <- A_loc[i]

  while (lower <= upper_limit) {
    if (B$loc[lower] >= current_loc - 100L) {
      break
    }

    if (count > 0L) {
      count <- count - 1L
      sum <- sum - B$value[lower]
    }

    lower <- lower + 1L
  }

  if (upper < lower) {
    upper <- lower
  }

  while (upper <= upper_limit) {
    if (B$loc[upper] > current_loc + 100L) {
      break
    }

    count <- count + 1L
    sum <- sum + B$value[upper]
    upper <- upper + 1L
  }

  out$n[i] <- count
  out$sum[i] <- sum
  out$avg[i] <- sum / count
}
```

Comment: When I run your example for the case described I get an output of 10,000 rows _(I presume one row for each row of `A`)_ with each row repeated between 2-63 times. The way I interpreted the question, the result should have one row per unique value of `A$loc`, so if sample is drawn from 1:1000, there should never been more than 1,000 rows in the output. _ (I had an output with 989 rows)_ @Jautis perhaps you could provide some clarification here? It's definitely looking like `C++` could be the superior solution here if the details of implementation are correct!

Comment: Oh I didn't check for duplicates, but you can avoid that with a call to `unique` (I've updated the answer).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution

```
library(tidyverse)

A = read.table(text = "
loc
150
250
400
", header=T)

B = read.table(text = "
loc    value
25     7
77     19
170    10
320    15
", header=T)

A %>%
  mutate(B = list(B)) %>%              # create all combinations of rows of A and B
  unnest() %>%
  filter(abs(loc - loc1) <= 100) %>%   # keep rows that satisfy your condition
  group_by(loc) %>%                    # for each loc values
  summarise(sum = sum(value),          # calculate sum
            avg = mean(value))         # calculate mean

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#     loc   sum   avg
#    <int> <int> <dbl>
# 1   150    29  14.5
# 2   250    25  12.5
# 3   400    15  15
```

Maybe not the best solution if you have large `A` and `B` tables as you have to create all combinations of rows and then filter.

Comment: I was typing a similar solution until I refreshed the page and saw yours. Maybe iterate through the `B` column to filter for locations within a 100 before unnesting?

Comment: @struggles that could be an option, but never needed to me so far. It would be interesting to simulate some very big data sets and try both ways and see the benefits.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with the `foverlaps` function within `data.table` and the following method actually has a prayer at finishing your actual use case -- *`A` which is thousands of rows and a table `B` which is nearly a millions of rows* -- in a reasonable amount of time.

---

#### With your toy example:

```
library(data.table)

A <- fread("
           loc
           150
           250
           400")

B <- fread("
           loc    value
           25     7
           77     19
           170    10
           320    15")

## Create a 'dummy' value to create an interval w/same start and end in A
A[,loc_Dummy := loc]

## Create values bounding the match range for loc in B
B[,loc_Plus100 := loc + 100]
B[,loc_Minus100 := loc - 100]

## Set up for the overlap join
setkey(A,loc,loc_Dummy)
setkey(B,loc_Minus100, loc_Plus100)

## Create a table of only matches instead of doing a full cartesian join of all cases
Matches <- foverlaps(A[,.(loc, loc_Dummy)],
                     B[,.(loc_Minus100,loc_Plus100,value)])

## Create a summary table
Matches[,.(n = .N, sum = sum(value), avg = mean(value)), by = .(loc)]

#    loc n sum  avg
# 1: 150 2  29 14.5
# 2: 250 2  25 12.5
# 3: 400 1  15 15.0
```

---

#### Scaling up - yikes!

However - this is actually an **extremely** computationally intensive problem. Scaling up to your actual case sizes shows the challenge here -- using 10,000 rows for table `A` and 1,000,000 rows for table `B`, this method completes in **91 seconds** on the server I'm running on, but uses **over 112 GB of memory**!

```
A <- data.table(loc = sample.int(1000, size = 1e4, replace = TRUE))


B <- data.table(loc = sample.int(1000, size = 1e6, replace = TRUE),
                value = sample.int(100, size = 1e6, replace = TRUE))

system.time({
  A[,loc_Dummy := loc]
  B[,loc_Plus100 := loc + 100]
  B[,loc_Minus100 := loc - 100]

  setkey(A,loc,loc_Dummy)
  setkey(B,loc_Minus100, loc_Plus100)

  Matches <- foverlaps(A[,.(loc, loc_Dummy)],
                       B[,.(loc_Minus100,loc_Plus100,value)])

  Summary  <- Matches[,.(n = .N, sum = sum(value), avg = mean(value)), by = .(loc)]

})

## Warning: Memory usage peaks at ~112 GB!

# user  system elapsed 
# 56.407  46.258  91.135
```

---

This is barely within the capabilities of the server I use, and likely may not actually be applicable for your case.

If you don't have hundreds of Gigabytes of memory at your disposal, you'll probably have to get a little more clever in the way you approach this and iterate through chunks at a time.

From what I can tell, your problem is actually similar in ways to the one posed (and solved) by Lorenzo Busetto and detailed in a blog post: [Speeding up spatial analyses by integrating `sf` and `data.table`: a test case](https://lbusettspatialr.blogspot.com/2018/02/speeding-up-spatial-analyses-by.html).

---

#### Chunking to the rescue

Requiring over ~100 Gigabytes of memory isn't *really* a feasible solution -- especially if you wanted to scale `A` or `B` up by an order of magnitude at some point.

However, a chunking method (inspired by Lorenzo's post linked above) that splits up the problem into 100 chunks *actually* only increases by run-time a trivial amount to **116 seconds**, but reduces peak memory usage to **less than 3 GB**! If I were planning on doing this in production, I'd go with something like the following.

*One note: I didn't really do some in-depth auditing on the accuracy of the results (I might have specified one of the range bounds incorrectly open or closed), so I'd scrutinize the output with the data you're familiar with before putting into production.*

```
A <- data.table(loc = sample.int(1000, size = 1e4, replace = TRUE))

B <- data.table(loc = sample.int(1000, size = 1e6, replace = TRUE),
                value = sample.int(100, size = 1e6, replace = TRUE))

system.time({

  A[,loc_Dummy := loc]
  B[,loc_Plus100 := loc + 100]
  B[,loc_Minus100 := loc - 100]

  setkey(A,loc)
  setkey(B,loc)

  ChunkCount <- 100
  ChunkSize <- A[,.N/ChunkCount]

  ResultList <- vector("list", ChunkCount) 

  for (j in seq_len(ChunkCount)){

    A_loc_Min <- A[((j-1)*ChunkSize + 1):(min(nrow(A),(j)*ChunkSize)), min(loc)]
    A_loc_Max <- A[((j-1)*ChunkSize + 1):(min(nrow(A),(j)*ChunkSize)), max(loc)]

    A_Sub <- A[loc >= A_loc_Min & loc < A_loc_Max]
    B_Sub <- B[loc_Plus100 >= A_loc_Min & loc_Minus100 < A_loc_Max]

    setkey(A_Sub,loc,loc_Dummy)
    setkey(B_Sub,loc_Minus100, loc_Plus100)

    Matches <- foverlaps(A_Sub[,.(loc, loc_Dummy)],
                         B_Sub[,.(loc_Minus100,loc_Plus100,value)])

    ResultList[[j]]  <- Matches[,.(n = .N, sum = sum(value), avg = mean(value)), by = .(loc)]

  }

  Summary  <- rbindlist(ResultList)

})

#    user  system elapsed 
# 109.125  16.864 116.129
```

### Validating

> Update: @Alexis and @Frank's suggestion in the comments generate the same result set, mine comes out slightly different, but only on the count. If someone else can verify that the correct answer is actually that provided by @Alexis/@Frank, then I'd be happy to retract my answer as both methods execute faster than the one I proposed.

```
set.seed(1234)

A <- data.table(loc = sample.int(1000, size = 1e3, replace = TRUE))

B <- data.table(loc = sample.int(1000, size = 1e4, replace = TRUE),
                value = sample.int(10, size = 1e4, replace = TRUE))



## Matt 
Matt_A <- copy(A)
Matt_B <- copy(B)

Matt_A[,loc_Dummy := loc]
Matt_B[,loc_Plus100 := loc + 100]
Matt_B[,loc_Minus100 := loc - 100]

setkey(Matt_A,loc,loc_Dummy)
setkey(Matt_B,loc_Minus100, loc_Plus100)

Matches <- foverlaps(Matt_A[,.(loc, loc_Dummy)],
                     Matt_B[,.(loc_Minus100,loc_Plus100,value)])

Summary_Matt  <- Matches[,.(n = .N, sum = sum(value), avg = mean(value)), keyby = .(loc)]


## Alexis

Rcpp::sourceCpp("RowRanges.cpp")

A_loc <- sort(A$loc, decreasing = FALSE)
B <- B[order(B$loc),]
Alexis <- foo(unique(A_loc), B$loc, B$value)

Summary_Alexis <- as.data.table(Alexis)
colnames(Summary_Alexis) <- c("n","sum","avg")

Summary_Alexis[,loc := unique(A_loc)]
setcolorder(Summary_Alexis, c("loc","n","sum","avg"))

## Frank

Frank <- A[, up := loc + 100][
  , dn := loc - 100][
    , c("n", "s", "m") := B[copy(.SD), on=.(loc >= dn, loc <= up), .(.N, sum(value), mean(value)), by=.EACHI][
      , .(N, V2, V3)]][]

Summary_Frank <- unique(Frank[,.(loc,n, sum = s, avg = m)][order(loc)])

## Comparing

all.equal(Summary_Frank,Summary_Alexis)
# [1] TRUE

all.equal(Summary_Frank,Summary_Matt)
# [1] "Column 'n': Mean relative difference: 1.425292"
```

Comment: Would you mind testing my solution? I don't know if it's completely sound.

Comment: @Alexis That makes two of us, I'm not 100% sure my implementation was perfect either! I am testing now to see if we generate the same output.

Comment: I didn't test yours, but an update non-equi join takes ~45 seconds on my comp with your last example. `system.time(A[, up := loc + 100][, dn := loc - 100][, c("n", "s", "m") := B[copy(.SD), on=.(loc >= dn, loc <= up), .(.N, sum(value), mean(value)), by=.EACHI][, .(N, V2, V3)]][])`

Comment: @Frank that method seems much more idiomatic, I felt like I was shoe-horning `foverlaps` in where it wasn't necessarily the best fit. I have a discrepancy between my result, but yours matches the one from @Alexis. Care to post your response as an answer representing a `data.table` solution? Then I can retract mine if someone else can verify that my count is coming out erroneous.

Comment: Ok, thanks for checking into it. I've posted, but also don't know which result is correct. Hopefully, the OP will clarify

Comment: Thanks a ton for this! The other methods may be faster but I loved your systematic way of laying things out

Answer (score 0):

I don't normally suggest solutions that rely on installing packages, but I think this one will do the trick for you. It will install a package that enables you to code in SQL inside R.

```
# Load the package
install.packages("sqldf")
library(sqldf)

# Create tables
A <- data.frame("loc"=c(150,250,400))
B <- data.frame("loc"=c(25,77,170,320),"value"=c(7,19,10,15))


# Join tables
df0 <- sqldf('select a.loc
                    ,count(b.value) as n_value
                    ,sum(b.value) as sum_value
                    ,avg(b.value) as avg_value
              from A as a
              left join B as b
              on abs(a.loc - b.loc) <= 100
              group by a.loc')

# Print data frame
df0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how well this solution will scale - it depends on whether the filter matrix fits in memory.

```
A <- within(A,{
 B.filter <- outer(B$loc, A$loc, function(x, y) abs(x - y) <= 100) 

 n <- colSums(B.filter)
 sum <- colSums(B$value * B.filter)
 avg <- sum / n
 rm(B.filter)
})
```

If locations in A and/or B repeat, you might be able to reduce the size of the filter matrix by only using unique values:

```
A <- within(A,{
 B.filter <- outer(unique(B$loc), unique(A$loc), function(x, y) abs(x - y) <= 100) 
 colnames(B.filter) <- unique(A$loc)
 rownames(B.filter) <- unique(B$loc)

 n <- colSums(B.filter[,as.character(A$loc)])
 sum <- colSums(B$value * B.filter[as.character(B$loc),])
 avg <- sum / n
 rm(B.filter)
})
```

Comment: interesting solution =).

Comment: only if it can scale big enough. :)