# Count number of rows within one second of current row timestamp

Tags: r

I have a set of CPU logging data that records data at uneven intervals. For each row, I would like to count the number of rows that occured within the last second of that partciular row. Example data in the first two columns, with the expected output in the third column. For the first n rows that occur less than a second from the start of the log, the output is NA.

```
timestamp (POSXIct)           data   output
2018-09-19 00:53:48.014469    123    NA
2018-09-19 00:53:48.031590    123    NA
2018-09-19 00:53:48.052569    123    NA
...
... 56 other rows not shown
...
2018-09-19 00:53:48.015465    123    60  --> first row that is >=1 sec from the start of the file
2018-09-19 00:53:48.017463    123    61  --> 61 rows within 1 sec from this time including this row
2018-09-19 00:53:48.018862    123    62  --> 62 rows within 1 sec from this time
2018-09-19 00:53:48.024468    123    62
2018-09-19 00:53:48.031869    123    61
2018-09-19 00:53:48.081869    123    50  --> 50 rows within 1 sec from this time
```

At the moment I am using a straight forward `for` loop, but the time is excessive for a reasonable amount of data. I've looked at trying to use a mix of floors, cumulative counts, findInterval, summarize, etc. but I could not see a way that works given the uneven interval period. Any ideas on a speedier implmentation?

Comment: If you post an easily reproducible example, it might be easier to help. For guidance on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/28481250#28481250 Re the question, if you just want ideas, a non-equi join can be used with the data.table package.

Comment: Seems like [Ronan's answer here could work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15960352/903061), create a `width` column with that answer and then use `zoo:rollapply` with the `length` function. (Or something like that.)

Comment: The logic required sounds similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50514654/5793905).